# Magento - Send a Friend redirects to a 404 page

Tags: php, magento

The Send a Friend form redirects to a 404 page. I have moved the Send a Friend from its individual page to the product details page. I made changes in "catalog.xml" for the layout of the page.

This is what I wrote in "catalog.xml:"

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title">
        <alias>send-friend</alias>
        <title>Send Friends</title>
        <block>sendfriend/send</block>
        <template>sendfriend/send.phtml</template>
    </action>
<!--    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>reviewsthis</alias><title>Review This Product</title><block>review/form</block><template>review/form.phtml</template></action> -->
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>reviews</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action> 
</block>
```

The problem is that the form is not getting the correct "action" URL. The statement in "send.phtml", i.e.

```
action="<?php echo $this->getSendUrl() ?>"
```

Returns this:

```
http://localhost/magento_test1/catalog/product/sendmail/id/130/
```

Whereas it should return something like this:

```
http://localhost/magento_test1/sendfriend/product/sendmail/id/171/cat_id/35/
```

The problem definitely occured when I moved the form into the product details page. Now, "$this->getSendUrl ()" gives a relative path from the product's page.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue? What am I missing? How can I make the function get the URL for the Sendfriend controller?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if the Send To A Friend module is disabled. Ensure you enable it by going to System->Configuration->Catalog->Email To A Friend.

*Edit*
Based on your comments it looks like the theme may not be 100% compatible with your current version of Magento. Therefore make sure the code that generates the Send To A Friend URL is correct:

Have a look in app/design/frontend/default//template/catalog/product/view.phtml and look for the bit of code for send to a friend. Make sure it looks like this:

```
<?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
    <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Module is enabled. I have changed "Allow for Guests" to "Yes" but still it is not working. Please, need help!